# Exclude adaptor from VPN or make accessible

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I'm running a home "server" with PLEX on win 7 with 2 adaptors. A wireless and a hardline. I have VPN running on the system but it makes the server unable to accept external connections, which is logical seeing the traffic runs through the VPN. But in this case it is unwanted seeing the system needs to be accessible from outside the network by upnp.

Is there a way to keep the server accessible through the isp's ip number and keep the VPN doing it's thing for all other traffic?

Comment: No, just run VMs for the stuff you want to tunnel and keep Plex open on the host - simplest

Comment: That sounds logical. Any ideas on how to run utorrent through the VPN?